# Numpy mask based on if a value is in some other list

Tags: python, numpy

I have searched high and low and just can't find a way to do it. (It's possible I was searching for the wrong terms.)

I would like to create a mask (eg: `[True False False True True]`) based on whether each value is in some other list.

```py
a = np.array([11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17])
mask = a in [14, 16, 8] #(this doesn't work at all!)
#I would like to see [False False False True False True False]
```

So far the best I can come up with is a list comprehension.

```py
mask = [True if x in other_list else False for x in my_numpy_array]
```

Please let me know if you know of some secret sauce to do this with NumPy and fast (computationally), as this list in reality is huge.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [`numpy.in1d()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html#numpy.in1d):

```
In [6]: np.in1d(a, [14, 16, 18])
Out[6]: array([False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: perfect I knew there had to be something :) I'll accept in 12 mins when it lets me ... thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer is right but currently `numpy`'s docs recommend using [`isin` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) instead of `in1d`