# finding indexes with where clause over multiple values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
np.where(A ==2)[0]
```

gives the indexes of `A` where elements are equal to 2.

How do you generalize to a list of possible values?

I am looking for something like:

```
np.where(A in ([2,3,6,8]))[0]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy - check if elements of a array belong to another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37913957/numpy-check-if-elements-of-a-array-belong-to-another-array)

Comment: Short story: use `np.isin` for your mask nowadays.

Comment: Or another duplicate: [Numpy mask based on if a value is in some other list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629061/numpy-mask-based-on-if-a-value-is-in-some-other-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [NumPy 1.13](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) you can use the `isin` function.

In prior versions there was [`in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html).

#### Test:

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(np.isin(A, [2, 3, 6, 8]))
```

#### Results:

```
[False  True  True False False]
```