# Creating a long masking list (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, bigdata, masking

Here is what I have:

long_list = a very long list of integer values (6M+ entries)

wanted_list = a list of integer values that are of interest (70K entries)

What I need:

mask_list = a list of booleans of the same length as long_list, describing whether each element of long_list in present in the wanted_list (i.e. [is long_list[0] in wanted_list?, is long_list[1] in wanted_list?,....]). The number of'True' entries in this list should be the same as len(wanted_list)

I got a working code using a for loop, but as expected it's way too slow for the length of the lists that I am working with (takes several minutes to run):

```
masklist = []

for element in long_list:
    if element in wanted_list:
        masklist.append(True)
    else: 
        masklist.append(False)
```

I was wondering if there is a more elegant and fast way to achieve this goal? I was looking into numpy.ma module, but could not think of an elegant way to apply it to this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy mask based on if a value is in some other list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629061/numpy-mask-based-on-if-a-value-is-in-some-other-list)

Comment: You are using the wrong data type for this type of operation.  Both of your collections of numbers should be held in `sets`.  Is index position of the match important in `long_list` or just the *values*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) for this:

```
masklist = np.isin(long_list, wanted_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is slow because the algorithm has a poor complexity (`O(n²)`). This can be done in `O(n)`:

```py
wanted_set = set(wanted_list)
masklist = [element in wanted_set for element in long_list]
```

If you operate on Numpy array, then you can use `np.unique` and `np.searchsorted` but it will be computed in `O(n log n)` time. It may be faster for small arrays (due to the Numpy implementation), but not for huge ones (due to the complexity and inefficient cache accesses). `np.isin` may also be useful and maybe faster.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! The code you suggested is definitely much more sustainable, and np.isin was the fastest option.